# Php: add to array within array

Tags: php, arrays, insert, merge, addition

Hey I am building JSON from array. It looks something like this:

```
  $jsonkk = array('fields' => [array(
  'x' => 107,
  'y' => 772,
  'width' => 204,
  'height' => 17,
  'page_number' => 0
  )]
  );
```

Now I would like to add another array into 'fields'so the result would look like this:

```
array('fields' => [array(
'x' => 107,
'y' => 772,
'width' => 204,
'height' => 17,
'page_number' => 0
),
(
'x' => 646,
'page_number' => 1
)]
);
```

How to add such arrays inside other arrays?

Comment: Wouldn't you just define the two arrays as separate variables and then incorporate the two variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers above and another way is;

```
 array_push($jsonkk['fields'], array('x'=>646, 'page_number' => 1));
```

or

```
 $jsonkk['fields'][] = array('x'=>456, 'page_number' => 1));
```

or to put in another array inside $jsonkk

```
 $jsonkk[] = array('x'=>456, 'page_number' => 1));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonk['fields'][] = array("x" => 646, "page_number" => 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $jsonkk['fields'][] = ['x'=>646, 'page_number'=>1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create another `array` with the `fields` key, then add them recursively.
Follow this link, i think it will help you.
[enter link description here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php)

```
$jsonkk = array(
    'fields' => array(
        array(
          'x' => 107,
          'y' => 772,
          'width' => 204,
          'height' => 17,
          'page_number' => 0
        )
     )
  );

$jsonkk_new = array(
    'fields' => array(
        array(
          'x' => 646,
          'page_number' => 1
        )
     )
  );

  $result = array_merge_recursive($jsonkk, $jsonkk_new);
  print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your notation means, doesnt look a var dump...

Anyway. There is no mistery to JSON, it just serializes data. Buikd your data whatever way you want, then convert to json with json_encode.

Now. If you dont know basic PHP datasets and how ro work with multidimensional arrays in it, that is another question :p

Comment: No I don't for this case, that why i asked. This form of notations is strictly required for my application and can't be done any other way